# Set operator precedence

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators, operator-precedence

In python, I am unable to understand the operator precedence.

```
a = set([1, 2, 3])

a|set([4])-set([2])
```

The above expression returns {1,2,3,4}. However, I thought the operator | shall be executed before - but this doesn't seem like happening.

When I apply parenthesis, it returns me the desired output, i.e. {1,3,4}

```
  (a|set([4]))-set([2])
```

So, my question is why is this happening and what is the operator (for set operators like -, |, &, ^, etc) precedence when applying set operations.

Comment: Assuming operators have a set precedence regardless of context, `-` has a higher precedence than `|`: http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~valerie/courses/fall10/155/resources/op_precedence.html

Comment: @Carcigenicate That is a valid assumption; the expression is parsed before the (run-time) types of any of the operands is known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) rules give priority to `-` operator and then to bitwise `|` operator:

Now we have a `set` with `union`, overloaded with `|`, and `difference`, oveloaded with `-`:

```
a = set([1, 2, 3])

a|set([4])-set([2])
```

The question now became: why do the same rules of precedence apply?

This is because python evaluates operator expressions applying the same rules precedence for all classes that overload the standard operators:

```
class Fagiolo:

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __or__(self, other):
        return Fagiolo("({}+{})".format(self.val, other.val))

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Fagiolo("({}-{})".format(self.val, other.val))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.val

red = Fagiolo("red")
white = Fagiolo("white")

new_born = red | white - Fagiolo("blue")

print(new_born)
```

gives:

```
(red+(white-blue))
```

Comment: `|` with sets isn't a bitwise operator; like `-`, it's *just* an operator whose actual operation is determined by the types it is used with. Operator precedence is decided by the *grammar*; operator *semantics* are determined by types (which aren't known until run-time).